# Homotopy between cellular maps: an additional property

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $f,g \colon X \to Y$ two cellular maps between (say) finite CW complexes such that $f\sim g$ via the homotopy $H \colon X \times I \to Y$.

> Are there any results that permits to modify the given homotopy $H$ such that for every $t \in I$, the map $H_t \colon X \to Y$ is cellular?

I read that there is a notion of cellular homotopy, but the definition **doesn't imply** the highlighted property. In fact an homotopy is said ti be cellular, if it is a cellular map from $X\times I \to Y$ seen as a map of CW complexes.

Comment: I think what you're asking for might be too restrictive. Take, for instance,  $\mathbb{S}^2$ viewed as two disks glued along a circle in the intuitive way and define a map $f:\mathbb{S}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ which just rotates the sphere about 180 degrees around an axis through the above circle. Then this map is clearly homotopic to the identity of $\mathbb{S}^2$ by simply rotating it back but if you require your homotopy to be cellular for any $t$ then a point on the inside of the disks can never cross the circle. This is just a wild guess though, don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Nephry Thanks for the example, I'm of the same idea of you, for the fact that I didn't find anything on the literature about it. But you know, maybe with some wild constructions and with some hypothesis something it can be done.. therefore the question

Comment: For what it's worth, the homotopy *can* be chosen to be cellular which means that $h(X^n\times I)\subset Y^{n+1})$. Not quite as good as being cellular at each time, but it's not too bad either.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment rather than an answer, but a bit too long for a comment.

There is a general notion of filtered space $X_*$, and of maps and homotopies between them, see [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html). Of course a CW-complex with its skeletal filtration is a key example,   In this book a homotopy such as you describe is called a *thin* homotopy, and these play a special role in the theory and applications. For example there are   rather obvious compositions in various directions, generalising the composition of paths,  of filtered maps  $I^n_* \to X_*$, where $I^n_*$ is the $n$-cube with its usual skeletal filtration;    a key result is that these compositions are inherited by thin homotopy classes, to give strict $n$-fold groupoids, generalising the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points.